# Retrieve actions on my page posts (comments, likes, shares) Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm developing an application where I need to get the comments and reactions that users made with the posts on our page. I was able to successfully complete the authentication and authorization process. I already have Marketing permissions enabled too.

I'm having trouble understanding through the documentation what the flow would be to get the post, then I'll get the comments and reactions, and finally the profiles that interacted.

I'm fetching the posts through this endpoint:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:83478076&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED&sharesPerOwner=100

With the following response:

```
{
"paging": {
    "start": 0,
    "count": 10,
    "links": [],
    "total": 2
},
"elements": [
    {
        "owner": "urn:li:organization:83478076",
        "activity": "urn:li:activity:6983392701052272640",
        "edited": false,
        "created": {
            "actor": "urn:li:person:RXLD4KJzcC",
            "time": 1664970565075
        },
        "text": {
            "text": "Publicação teste 2"
        },
        "lastModified": {
            "actor": "urn:li:csUser:0",
            "time": 1664970565122
        },
        "id": "6983392700481851392",
        "distribution": {
            "linkedInDistributionTarget": {
                "visibleToGuest": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "owner": "urn:li:organization:83478076",
        "activity": "urn:li:activity:6967163462971998208",
        "edited": false,
        "created": {
            "actor": "urn:li:person:RXLD4KJzcC",
            "time": 1661101213162
        },
        "text": {
            "text": "Publicação de teste"
        },
        "lastModified": {
            "actor": "urn:li:csUser:0",
            "time": 1661101213210
        },
        "id": "6967163462233780224",
        "distribution": {
            "linkedInDistributionTarget": {
                "visibleToGuest": true
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

What would be the flow to get the comments of the posts listed in the response? Do I need any premium account to gain access?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Comments API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/comments-api?view=li-lms-2023-01&tabs=http#get-comments-on-shares).

Sample request:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/{shareUrn|ugcPostUrn|commentUrn}/comments
```

---

Alternatively:

- To retrieve single comment ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/comments-api?view=li-lms-2023-01&tabs=http#get-a-comment))

Sample request:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/{shareUrn|ugcPostUrn|commentUrn}/comments/{commentId}
```

- To retrieve multiple comments ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/comments-api?view=li-lms-2023-01&tabs=http#batch-get-a-collection-of-comments))

Sample request:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/{shareUrn|ugcPostUrn|commentUrn}/comments/ids=List({commentId})
```